# Adding values that are both at index 1 of a tuple

Tags: python

```
`data_sorted = [('Alabama', 4699671, 163629, 0.03294111631266611, 104018,
 0.02094047532290061), ('Alaska', 684530, 57364, 0.07484024496207367, 24592,
 0.032084082422901394)]
```

What I have so far:

```
def calc_totals(data_sorted):
    for line in data_sorted:
        tot_nat_born = int(i[1])
        print(tot_nat_born)`
```

How would I get the calc_totals() to take both indices of 1 and add them together, basically making it (4699671 + 648530)?

Comment: How would you do it naively? Can you write a `for` loop? Can you index into tuples? If yes, what is stopping you from trying? If no, why not?

Comment: I started using a for loop and I got it to find both numbers at index 1, but I'm not sure how I would add them together.

Comment: Please share your code. Your question will be received much better if we can see that you tried something.

Comment: I just edited to show what I have so far. All I have is finding the numbers at that index, but I don't know how to add these two numbers.

Comment: `int(i[1])` is a typo, I assume you meant `line[1]`? And there's no need for `int()` because it's already an int.

Comment: Essentially you want to sum one column in a dataframe. ***pandas*** does this.

Comment: @smci So does the standard library. That is an overpowered tool for what OP is trying to do.

Comment: @mypetlion Because noone ever just wants to sum one column of one dataset. Likely they will use some the other operations: indexing, filtering, tabulation, other stats, merging to another table, grouping etc. If not today then tomorrow. There's no point in setting out to manually write that sort of code in base Python. But yes if  summing one column of one dataset was all the OP ever wanted to do, then yes base Python can handle it.

Comment: @CodeGuy7153 something still unclear?

Answer (score 2):

If you change `i` in your code to `line`, you are successfully printing the second element of each inner tuple. (The call to `int` seems unnecessary since you are already expecting ints at position two.)

What you need to do now is to add these values together and return the total. This is the most straight forward implementation:

```
def calc_totals(data):
    total = 0
    for record in data:
        total += record[1]
    return total
```

The idea is to initialize `total` to zero and then add the second element `record[1]` of every data-record in `data` to `total`.

**Demo**

```
>>> data_sorted = [('Alabama', 4699671, 163629, 0.03294111631266611, 104018,
...: 0.02094047532290061), ('Alaska', 684530, 57364, 0.07484024496207367, 24592,
...: 0.032084082422901394)]
...: 
>>> calc_totals(data_sorted)
>>> 5384201
```

... and if you want to get fancy:

```
>>> from operator import itemgetter
>>> sum(map(itemgetter(1), data_sorted))
>>> 5384201
```

... or with `sum` and a generator-expression:

```
>>> sum(record[1] for record in data_sorted)
>>> 5384201
```

If the last two solutions seem weird, just come back to them once you got the basics of Python down.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in base Python `tot_nat_born = sum(line[1] for line in data_sorted)`, but...

***pandas*** package does 2D data manipulation way better, in fact the solution to summing a column in pandas is just `df[1].sum()`:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame( [('Alabama', 4699671, 163629, 0.03294111631266611, 104018,  0.02094047532290061), ('Alaska', 684530, 57364, 0.07484024496207367, 24592,  0.032084082422901394)] )

>>> df[1]
0    4699671
1     684530
Name: 1, dtype: int64

df[1].sum()
5384201
```

Check out the quickstart [10 Minutes to pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/10min.html)

Comment: Better in what way? How is this easier to do and understand than `sum(item[1] for item in data_sorted)`?

Comment: "Better" because noone ever just wants to sum one column of one dataset. Likely they will use some the other operations: indexing, filtering, tabulation, other stats, merging to another table, grouping etc. If not today then tomorrow. There's no point in setting out to manually write that sort of code in base Python.